# pdfmake - fs.readFileSync is not a function error

Tags: node.js, webpack, pdfmake

I'm trying to use this lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake. 
I have installed it with npm, and I'm importing it using webpack 2.

The browser console shows this error:

> fs.readFileSync is not a function error

The examples in the library website are importing the javascript files and generating the PDF, everything in the front-end. But this code seems to be a server-side nodejs code. That's confusing.

Here's my webpack.config file

```
let webpack = require('webpack');
let path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry:'./main.js',
  output: {path: __dirname, filename:'bundle.js'},
  node: {
    fs: "empty"
  },
  module:{
    loaders:[{
      test: /.jsx?$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
        presets:['es2015','react','stage-1'],
        plugins: [
          'transform-decorators-legacy'
        ]
      }
    },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" },


      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
          loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
        }, {
          loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
        }, {
          loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried to change `fs:true` but then I've got the following message from webpack itself:

> Error: No browser version for node.js core module 'fs' available

How do I proceed with this question?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any chance you can put your webpack config here for us to see?

Comment: added the webpack.config and some more details about the problem to the edit

Answer (score 0):

Looking at their source code, it seems like they have a `fs` alternative [here](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/master/src/browser-extensions/virtual-fs.js) and in their webpack they just load that and give it a 'fs' alias to simulate node's fs.

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        fs: path.join(__dirname, './src/browser-extensions/virtual-fs.js')
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in frontend mode, you need to require it explicitly :

```
window.pdfMake = require('pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js');
var vfs = require('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js');
window.pdfMake.vfs = vfs.pdfMake.vfs;
```